# OS X Terminal command line prompt hostname changed to unknownXXXXXXXXXXXX

Tags: macos, terminal

After installing new versions of Ruby on Rails through [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) my command line prompt changed to unknownf81edfdc0983. Why is this happening, and how do I switch it back to normal? It used to display my computer's name (i.e. gabriels-MacBook-Pro). 
I have rebooted and restarted my terminal, and I don't think I'm running any Ruby in my profile. My computer name on System Preferences is Gabriel’s MacBook Pro.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you rebooted?  Have you restarted terminal?  Do you run any Ruby in your profile?  How does your computer identify itself?  Simply installing RoR should not affect your terminal at all.  Your question is in danger of being closed as 'off topic'; it is border-line on topic here in my view.  You might get a more receptive response on the [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) site, but they'll likely want to know answers to the questions I raised.

Comment: Thanks. I will be careful when posting my questions. Let me edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Based on the blog referenced in [joerick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/382749/joerick)'s answer, it is likely that your DHCP or BootP server, or the reverse DNS lookup, is yielding the `unknown<MAC address>` (where that [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is unrelated to it being a Mac).  So, look to your network infrastructure for an explanation.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you so much for your answers. I will look more into that.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably nothing to do with Rails, it's probably your DHCP server giving you a hostname.

You can reset it using

```
$ sudo hostname gabriels-MacBookPro
```

EDIT:  See http://excitedcuriosity.wordpress.com/2007/08/24/mac-os-x-hostname-determination/

Comment: The x-ref'd blog entry is a little dated, unfortunately.  On my (slightly dated) 10.7.5, the `/etc/hostconfig` file contains (slash for newline): `# This file is going away /
AFPSERVER=-NO- /
AUTHSERVER=-NO- /
TIMESYNC=-NO- /
QTSSERVER=-NO-`.  Note that there is no HOSTNAME entry as mentioned in the blog.  However, the name determination sequence (DHCP or BootP, Reverse DNS, System Preferences, `localhost`) is likely to be close to the algorithm used.

Comment: Thanks. I got it back to what it was, and thanks for giving me more insights as to what is the main cause of the change!